# Removing Duplicates with hook_views_prerender

Tags: views, hooks

I have a view (filtering on content) that is returning duplicates. I am trying to used hook_view_prerender to remove those duplicates... but even after running this, I still get duplicates... Any ideas? Here's my function (and yes I know the function is running):

`function customedm_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  $used_nids = array();
  if ($view->name == 'new_resources'){
    echo ('hi');
    foreach ($view->result as $row){
        if (!in_array($row->nid, $used_nids)) {
          $new_view_result[] = $row;
          $used_nids[] = $row->nid;
        }
      }
    $view->result = $new_view_result;
    }
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to do this - simply use [Distinct](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp).

Edit the View, open the Advanced section -> Query Settings -> check the "Distinct" checkbox and save the view.

Edit:
In case you do use Distinct already, there are some cases where this can occur. Here is an issue discussing this - https://www.drupal.org/node/1765730, and this one has a code example that manipulates the result similarly to what you are trying to do - https://www.drupal.org/node/1223448#comment-4757898

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned that the distinct box is checked, and I am still returning duplicates on my filter...

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but someone might end up here (as I did) because distinct or even aggregation does not always remove all duplicates.
In the specific example above, the $new_view_result array should have been declared outside of the loop(foreach).
Here's code that would work in Drupal 8 / 9 / 10:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 */
function customedm_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if (
    $view->storage->id() == 'new_resources' &&
    $view->current_display == 'block_1'
  ) {
    $used_nids = [];
    $new_view_result = [];
    foreach ($view->result as $row) {
      if (!in_array($row->nid, $used_nids)) {
        $new_view_result[] = $row;
        $used_nids[] = $row->nid;
      }
    }
    $view->result = $new_view_result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct

The views distinct module has removed all duplicates from my views.